# jQuery .autosuggest retains results

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

my jquery autocomplete plugin retains the results of an initial search and does not replace these with the results of a new search.
My ASP code is as follows:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" class="controls_icr_searchbox" runat="server" 
                    style="width:200px;"/>
</form>
</body>
```

While the jQuery that makes the Ajax call looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
        $('.controls_icr_searchbox').keyup(function () {
            if ($('.controls_icr_searchbox').val().length > 4) {
                //Code to fetch
                //var divToBeWorkedOn = '#AjaxPlaceHolder';
                var parameters = "{'query':'" + 
                                    $('.controls_icr_searchbox').val() + "'}";
                var url = 'AutoComplete.asmx/GetAddress';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: parameters,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var datafromServer = data.d.split(":");
                        $("[class$='controls_icr_searchbox']").autocomplete({
                            source: datafromServer
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
          });    
    });
```

The ajax call returns the results fine each time but they don't appear to be bound on the .autocomplete event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of my problem.
After successfully pulling back the results of the Ajax Query I tried to assign them to the autocomplete using the following code:

```
$("[class$='controls_icr_searchbox']").autocomplete({
```

Strangely this worked on the first instance but failed on any subsequent changes.
My code now works correctly using the following code in place of the above:

```
$(".controls_icr_searchbox").autocomplete({
```